# Symfony 3 OneToMany relationship error

Tags: php, symfony

i'm trying to create a OneToMany form, and the symfony profiler throws an entity error, here's the code:

Tasks.php

```
<?php

namespace ShopBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="task")
 */
class Tasks
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true,length=100)
     * 
     */
    protected $description;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShopBundle\Entity\Tags", cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="name")
     */
    protected $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag(Tags $tag)
    {
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }

    public function removeTag(Tags $tag)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
    }
}
```

this is the Tags.php

```
<?php

namespace ShopBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tag")
 */
class Tags
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ShopBundle\Entity\Tasks", inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task")
     */
    protected $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

the profiler throws 2 errors:
The association ShopBundle\Entity\Tasks#tags refers to the owning side field ShopBundle\Entity\Tags#name which is not defined as association, but as field.

and

The association ShopBundle\Entity\Tasks#tags refers to the owning side field ShopBundle\Entity\Tags#name which does not exist.

it saves the data into the database, but i can't get the data from the database

Comment: I've tried to create your two entities and I don't get any error.

Comment: really? i get the same error, even after i delete the cache folder, restart nginx, restart the pc, every time, that's weird

Comment: Yeah, I get the message `[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.` and the following query dump `CREATE TABLE tasks (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;` and `CREATE TABLE tags (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, task INT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX IDX_6FBC9426527EDB25 (task), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;` and `ALTER TABLE tags ADD CONSTRAINT FK_6FBC9426527EDB25 FOREIGN KEY (task) REFERENCES tasks (id);`

Comment: If you replace `mappedBy="name"` by `mappedBy="tasks"` in Task.php and replace `$name` by `$tasks` and remove `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="task")` in Tags.php (so you let Symfony handle everything), do you still have your error? Also does `php bin/console d:s:v` only point the two error your wrote above?

Comment: yes, the same error, the command 'php bin/console d:s:v' only shows those 2 errors, database schema is in sync

Comment: i found the solution, and you were absolutely right, there was no error, i had to clear the symfony cache and the redis cache and it's all good now, thanks dude

Comment: Ah, this happen sometimes indeed...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check what debug CLI tells you:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

Look at this example from Doctrine docs [One-To-Many, Bidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

In `Tags@JoinColumn` you should add also field name of fields in entity `Tasks`, which you want to be connected with. (`referencedColumnName`)

Also I can see that `$name` is not a field, where you want to keep this mapped entity? Try to add another field with name of entity instead of putting annotations before `$name` (btw. it's also misleading to expect Tag name, but getting Entity `Task`).

For example :

```
// Tags.php

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ShopBundle\Entity\Tasks", inversedBy="tags")
 * @JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $task;
```

Then remember to change also mapping in `Tasks` entity:

```
// Tasks.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShopBundle\Entity\Tags", 
 * cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="task")
 */
 protected $tags;
```

Finally update your schema:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Hope it helps

Comment: Unless you want to use something else than `id`, `referencedColumnName` isn't needed... Him changing `name` to `task` is because he don't want to see `tasks_id` as column, unless you want to change the column name, `name` isn't needed either... I tried his entities, and they valid just fine, there is no error... His problem comes from something else. Also, don't force update your schema, dump it first... You woudln't want to loose some precious data... ;)